# how require returns the same file on all requires when dynamic names are used in requireJS

Tags: javascript, dynamic, requirejs, require

Kind of lost here...

I have a function that checks for template triggers on a page and when found triggers templating rendering by first requiring the template (using `requireJS`) and then building whatever the template is.

My problem is, I'm always requesting the first template file although when I do this:

```
renderTemplateTrigger: function(){
    var t = $('.template'),
        tl = t.length,
        i,
        dyn,
        el,
        config;

    if ( tl > 0 ){
        for ( i = 0; i < tl; i+=1 ){
            el = t[i];
            // correct element here
            console.log( el );

            if ( el.getAttribute("val") === null ){
                el.setAttribute("val",true);

                // get and parse configuration info
                config = el.getAttribute("data-config");
                dyn = $.parseJSON( config );
                // correct 
                console.log( dyn );

                // load template WILL ALWAYS LOAD THE SAME FILE
                require(['text!../tx/'+dyn.lib], 
                    function ( lib_template) {
                          // stuff  
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when `dyn.lib` in two iterations equals `listview` and `controlgroup` I'm requiring `listview` and `listview` and have no idea why?

**Question**:
Why do I seem to not be able to load different templates using dynamic template names with requireJS?

Comment: The contents of `controlgroup` isn't accidentally the same as that of `listview`, so it only seems like you are requiring the same template twice?

Comment: no. I checked that, too :-) The problem is `dyn.lib` inside the require callback is always `listview` no matter what I set it to outside. Maybe has to do with require async calling? or caching?

Comment: Can you check dyn? --> console.log(JSON.stringify(dyn))

Comment: Outside of the require call `dyn` is correct, in the callback it is always the same (= wrong, because it should contain the config info for the respective widget).

Comment: I think I have an idea. Since everything inside the callback is "stale" (if I have 10 templates, it will probably still use the first template dyn all the time), I guess I must only trigger an event inside the require call to let me know the file has loaded ... trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
...

dyn.f = function (lib_template)  {
  // stuff
};
require(['text!../tx/'+dyn.lib], dyn.f);

...
```

Comment: ah. that looks good. Give me a christmas to think about and then try! Thanks!

Comment: ok. Finally figured it out. I have plucked all my templates into a single template and now run the whole function inside the callback, so then there is no async problems anymore